# Konsole bashrc line overwriting issue

Tags: kubuntu, konsole

So I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and wanted to use the Parrot OS .bashrc I had already done that but I had to wipe my laptop and reinstall it. But upon reinstalling and putting the same .bashrc as parrot I get this issue where, when I write long command lines the first line gets overwritten by the next text (See image below) BTW when I use it in root I don't get this issue.

Before : [image]

After : [image]

And when I use Up Arrow : [image]

and this is the .bashrc https://gist.github.com/rickdaalhuizen90/d1df7f6042494b982db559efc01d9557

Comment: Have you tried a different terminal emulator to see if the problem persists there?  I've only seen this behaviour myself sometimes when resizing a terminal window and it gets confused about the multiline PS1.

Comment: You may have not /bin/bash defined as your user default shell. In case of (k)ubuntu you may have /bin/sh pointing to /bin/dash, but not /bin/bash.

Comment: @Egon Same issue with xterm

Comment: @Yurko never done that but let me explain one thing. First time I had the same issue I let it because 'f... it' but I had to wipe and reinstall kubuntu and there was no issue, then I found out I needed more space so I wiped out again and now this time the same issue as the first time... Idk what made it work the second time and didn't change anything with /bin/dash or /bin/bash :/ if I don't find the problem i'll leave it at that or put the original back but what "tilts me" is that when i'm using root with it i don't get that issue

Comment: This is probably your `PS1`. Try setting it to something very simple to narrow down the problem. `export PS1='\h: \w '`

Comment: @Sman865 it's not *just* the PS1 though, I use a similar multiline PS1 and tested setting mine to all three from the linked bashrc and couldn't replicate the problem on my end.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` return?

Comment: @guillermochamorro /bin/bash

Comment: not enough info.. trying to guess. try to make shell to check terminal window size after each command `shopt -s checkwinsize`

Comment: @Yurko well without the -s its says checkwinsize "on", with the -s I get nothing